# 'Index for header <column name> is 1 but CSVRecord only has one values' error in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm splitting a CSV file into two based on their row values (whether they have error values or not, and cells containing 999 are considered errors). but when I run it through the QueryRecord processor, I get the error below. What could be the possible fix for this?

> Sample CSV
>
> ```
> GradeNm ,CattleBreedNm ,CattleGenderNm ,Price
> C++     ,beef_cattle   ,Female         ,10094
> C++     ,hanwoo        ,Female         ,12001
> C++     ,beef_cattle   ,Male           ,12704
> B++     ,milk_cow      ,Female         ,16942
> 999     ,hanwoo        ,Male           ,error999
> A++     ,hanwoo        ,Male           ,17952
> D++     ,hanwoo        ,Female         ,8940
> 999     ,hanwoo        ,Female         ,error999
> 999     ,beef_cattle   ,Male           ,error999
> 999     ,hanwoo        ,Male           ,error999
> ```

- Query Record-Setting

[image]

- CSV reader setting

[image]

- The Error

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This was due to my CSV file containing a line with less than 4 fields. I mistakenly added a blank line at the end of the CSV file and that was causing the problem